# Exception handlers should preserve the original exception

Tags: logging, sonarqube

When running SonarQube an exception is found called "Exception handlers should preserve the original exception". Full exception description [here](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1166?layout=true).

The meaning is clear to us. The problem is that we are the following statement seems to be allowed by the compiler (see Compliant Solution):

```
 try { /* ... */ } catch (Exception e) { LOGGER.info("context", e); }
```

We are not using LOGGER, but:

```
trc.traceRaw(DcWxTaTrc.INFO, "Exception <" + e.getMessage() + ">
   ignored");
```

Is there a way to allow this kind of logging too? If yes: how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the logger you use to log the issue. If you have a look at the updated description : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1166

> // Noncompliant - exception is lost (only message is preserved)
>   try { /* ... */ } catch (Exception e) { LOGGER.info(e.getMessage()); }

An issue is raised because you keep only the message of the exception and so you lose the information about the stacktrace which should be logged according to the rule.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response! I did not saw that before :)

Comment: when we catch an exception, we know that exception may throw in some situation. so we catch that and implement or logic in catch block(may be dont need any action. but why we most preserved exception, and why is critical issue?